# sqlalchemy is not returning updated row information

Tags: python, mysql, database, sqlalchemy

I have a web application that is on top of mysql. When I started it, I built the mysql database from scratch, and connected to it using pymysql.

Fast forward...

I've rewritten everything using sqlalchemy to connect to the db (non-declarative?) I can connect to the db, read the db, update, etc. I also use MySQLWorkbench to view the database in a graphic way.

My webapp has a few tables that will poll the database for changes, and update the table. For instance, I have a job queue which will update the percentage-done. Here's the kicker:

When I send a job through, I will watch the database in MySQLWorkbench. I can verify that the job is going through (I see the percentage climbing). This confirms that the webapp is writing to the database. But! On the other end, where the table is asking for the status, it is not recieving the updated information (I've done print outs in the models, as well as in the flask app, as well as the FE js).

What is going on here? Even though I can see it in MySQLWorkbench is the connection not 'releasing' or something? Here is some of my code:

```
#models.py
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker, Query
import os
import json


Base = automap_base()

engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://user:asdas758ef10d2364d54d7e8@localhost:{}/metadatacontroller".format(3306))

# reflect the tables
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)

EncodeQueue = Base.classes.encode_queue

db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

class DataStore:
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = db_session()

    #receive status
    def queue_rendering_items(self):
        query = self.db.query(EncodeQueue).filter(EncodeQueue.status.in_(['queue', 'rendering', 'rendering thumbnails'])).all()
        return_query = []
        for item in query:
            row = {'artist_id': item.artist_id,
                   'art_id': item.art_id,
                   'status': item.status,
                   'progress': item.errors,
                   'artwork_title': item.artwork_title,
                   'artist_name': item.artist_name,
                   }
            return_query.append(row)

        return return_query

    #update status
    def update_render_progress(self, job_id, progress):
        self.db.query(EncodeQueue).filter_by(job_id=job_id).update\({'errors': json.dumps(progress)})
        self.db.commit()
```

(ignore the back slash in `update_render_progress` ... weird SO formatting)

This is how 'status' code is being called on a flask end point:

```
@app.route('/api/jobs', methods=["GET"])
def get_all_jobs():
    db = models.DataStore()
    all_art = db.queue_rendering_items()
    print(all_art)

    return jsonify({'data':all_art})
```

Lastly, the status is being updated by a different file, on a different machine:

```
import models
db = models.DataStore()    
db.update_render_progress(job_id, {'percentage': percentage_complete, 'time_remain': render.render_estimated_seconds_remaining})
```

What the heck is happening?

Comment: How are you calling this code?

Comment: @Blurp updated.

Comment: Where is `update_render_progress()` called?

Comment: @Blurp added :-) (separate file)

Comment: This might be due to MySQL's default transaction isolation level REPEATABLE_READ, though it is a bit mysterious how. If it should happen that your `/api/jobs` route handler were to use the same connection between calls, without a rollback or commit in between, the transaction would keep on seeing the same state it had when it began. Try adding a call to `self.db.session.rollback()` before the query in `db.queue_rendering_items()` and see what happens.

Comment: I noticed that you're not using Flask-SQLAlchemy, so have you remembered to hook the session to the request/app life cycle as described [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/sqlalchemy/#manual-object-relational-mapping)? If not, then I'm pretty sure that you're leaking transactional state between requests.